# Problem getting results with php and mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've a problem by running this php script:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "*******", "adsb");

/* check connection */
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $link->connect_error);
}

$query = "SELECT aircrafts.id, heli.reg, heli.hex, heli.typ, heli.opp, aircrafts.flight, aircrafts.altitude, aircrafts.lat, aircrafts.lon, aircrafts.squawk, aircrafts.message_date FROM `aircrafts` JOIN `heli` ON aircrafts.hex=heli.hex WHERE aircrafts.id='2414';";
$query .= "SELECT aircrafts.id, plane.reg, plane.hex, plane.typ, plane.opp, aircrafts.flight, aircrafts.altitude, aircrafts.lat, aircrafts.lon, aircrafts.squawk, aircrafts.message_date FROM `aircrafts` JOIN `plane` ON aircrafts.hex=plane.hex WHERE aircrafts.id='2414'";

$result = mysqli_multi_query($query);
/* execute multi query */
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<h1>INFO ABOUT FLIGHT RECORD &nbsp;" . $id . "</h1>";
    echo "<table><th>Registratie</th><th>ICAO24</th><th>Type</th><th>Operator</th><th>Callsign</th><th>Squawk</th><th>Time</th></tr>";

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td><a href='aircraft.php?hex=" . $row["hex"] . "'>" . $row["reg"] . "</a></td><td>" . $row["hex"] . "</td><td><img src='/database/SilhouttesLogos/" . $row["typ"] . ".bmp' /></td><td><img src='/database/OperatorFlags/" . $row["opp"] . ".bmp' /></td><td>" . $row["flight"] . "</td><td>" . $row["squawk"] . "</td><td>" . $row["message_date"] . "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
```

When I run the 2 query's in phpmyadmin I get 1 result.
(When I run 1 query on my site I get a result too, see code at the bottom of this post)
But when I run it on my site it's shows "0 results".

So... There must be a fould in the $result section.

Who can help? :-)

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "*****";
$dbname = "adsb";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT aircrafts.id, heli.reg, heli.hex, heli.typ, heli.opp, aircrafts.flight, aircrafts.altitude, aircrafts.lat, aircrafts.lon, aircrafts.squawk, aircrafts.message_date FROM `aircrafts` JOIN `heli` ON aircrafts.hex=heli.hex WHERE aircrafts.id=2414";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><th>Registratie</th><th>ICAO24</th><th>Type</th><th>Operator</th><th>Callsign</th><th>Squawk</th><th>Time</th></tr>";

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td><a href='aircraft.php?hex=" . $row["hex"] . "'>" . $row["reg"] . "</a></td><td>" . $row["hex"] . "</td><td><img src='/database/SilhouttesLogos/" . $row["typ"] . ".bmp' /></td><td><img src='/database/OperatorFlags/" . $row["opp"] . ".bmp' /></td><td>" . $row["flight"] . "</td><td>" . $row["squawk"] . "</td><td>" . $row["message_date"] . "</td></tr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: **WARNING**: It's important that you **DO NOT** use `mysqli_multi_query`. That function does not support placeholder values, something critical to securing your application. It's also extremely important to verify that each statement succeeds before proceeding to the next, slamming in a bunch of queries and ignoring errors is how you create huge problems.

Comment: You also can't chain two `SELECT` queries together without fetching data from each in turn. What you probably mean to do is `JOIN` together the two tables into a single query you then fetch.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code. You're mixing and matching styles here for no apparent reason.

Comment: Plus, `$result = mysqli_multi_query($query);` the connection was never made.

Comment: Check your error log as this code should be producing multiple errors due to incorrect arguments, as Funky Forty Niner points out.

Comment: Solve it with the 'union' command -> (SELECT bla bla bla) union (SELECT bla bla bla)

Answer (score -1):

This is probably your specific problem.

```
$result = mysqli_multi_query($query);
```

Here is the [PHP Doc](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

You need to establish the connection.

```
$result = mysqli_multi_query($link, $query);
```

Like the others mentioned in the comments, I would refactor this code.